# Phoenix migration or seeds for inserting data into lookup table

Tags: database, elixir, phoenix-framework, lookup-tables

I am fairly new to Elixir/Phoenix and I am not sure what is considered a better practice for inserting data into a lookup table. The data will be a fixed set of data but may expand over time as more records are needed.

I see most examples use `Repo.insert!` in seeds. Are seeds meant to be used as more of a base development data set? Would it be considered the better practice to create migrations to create this data in a migration so that it is guaranteed to only run once for each environment?

Comment: very good question, thanks! I also wondered if seeds was for populating dev environments. It would be nice to have this information on the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your use case, but in 99.9% of cases you should do that in seeds. You should query your data in migrations only if this is needed for creating constraints and/or computing values for newly added fields.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the reply!